# XAMPP v1.7.4 installation issues,local host not working

Tags: php, wordpress, joomla, apache2, xampp

I had an older version on XAMPP and it was working fine. I uninstalled it to install the new version.Since then local host has stopped working. XAMPP control panel says Apache and MySQL running.Can some one help please? I have got this in the httpd-vhosts.conf,do i make any changes here?

```
##<VirtualHost *:80>
    ##ServerAdmin postmaster@dummy-host.localhost
    ##DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host.localhost"
    ##ServerName dummy-host.localhost
    ##ServerAlias www.dummy-host.localhost
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.localhost-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.localhost-access.log" combined
##</VirtualHost>

##<VirtualHost *:80>
    ##ServerAdmin postmaster@dummy-host2.localhost
    ##DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host2.localhost"
    ##ServerName dummy-host2.localhost
    ##ServerAlias www.dummy-host2.localhost
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.localhost-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.localhost-access.log" combined
##</VirtualHost>
```

Thank You

Comment: what you get when visit this page [http://localhost](http://localhost/) can you access it via going to 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: Ive had skype installed while i had the earlier versio.But I still went to Skype>tools>options>advanced>connections>unchecked use port 80 and 443 alternatives for incoming connections

Comment: @Muntasir wow its working in 127.0.0.1 !! thanks for that but why didnt it work on localhost? am i doing something wrong??

Comment: when i visit the page http://localhost/ i get "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also fix it by editing your host file usually located in %systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

first of all backup your hosts file

comment this line by adding # at the beginning of the line(if its already their)

```
#::1 localhost
```

add this line in the end of the file

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

save it and restart your pc

if you face any problem just restore your hosts file

Comment: ::1             localhost This i what i have got at the moment,if i edit to ur advice will it mess up my IIS server.I have stopped it now to run apache

Comment: ::1 Localhost is the equivalent to 127.0.0.1 Localhost but in ipv6 protocol , you can add 127.0.0.1 Localhost this line also and that will be ipv4 , if something goes wrong with iss just revert back

Answer (score 0):

As you can access it using `127.0.0.1` and not 'localhost', locate `httpd-vhosts.conf`, usually in `C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/` and make sure you have the following listed as a virtual host:

```
  <VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
  </VirtualHost>
```

Then restart Apache from the XAMPP control panel.

Comment: i have posted the listing in the httpd-vhosts.conf i have above,could you please tell me where i need to make the changes?

Comment: @manraj82 - Yeah, paste the lines in my answer at the end of the `httpd-vhosts.conf`. The existing lines are just examples commented out with a `##`. Restart Apache from the Xammp control and see if it works.

Comment: Sorry mate no luck,did exactly like u said but not working.still working in 127.0.0.1

Comment: You could also try making sure the DocumentRoot is pointing to your correct files and check out the Apache logs to see if there was an error: `C:/xampp/apache/logs/error.log`. Lastly you could try adding the line stated by @Munstasir to the hosts file here: `C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts`. Again restart Apache.Good luck.