# xampp 1.7.3 upgrade broken virtual hosts access forbidden

Tags: xampp, dropbox, virtual-hosts

I've got a similar issue to that reported by another user here
[XAMPP v1.7.4 installation issues,local host not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371858/xampp-v1-7-4-installation-issues-local-host-not-working)

Upgrading xampp to 1.7.3 (osx) in my case has broken my virtual hosts.

In /etc/hosts I've got

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost  
fe80::1%lo0     localhost

127.0.0.1 mysite.test
```

In /Applications/XAMPP/etc/httpd.conf I've got:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so #uncommented
Include /Applications/XAMPP/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf #uncommented
```

In /Applications/XAMPP/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf I've got:
    # Use name-based virtual hosting.
    NameVirtualHost *:80
    NameVirtualHost *:443

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mysite.test
  DocumentRoot "/path-to-mysite/"
  <Directory "/path-to-mysite/">
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When tryng to access mysite.test Apache is logged in the following error
    [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: access to / denied

I've deleted the .htaccess, and repaired my disk permissions in case that was causing the problem.

Can anyone suggest what I might be missing?

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that there isn't a changed permission in your main `.conf` file. Could be an `AllowOverride None` or something that is causing the problem.

Comment: Hi Inquam, wouldn't that be overridden by the directive above? the main .conf does start with an AllowOverride None, but I thought any more local directives over-rode that.

Comment: If the main `.conf` has an `AllowOverride None` then that could very well be your problem (depending on the folder it's connected to etc). Since this could tell the server that no overrides are permitted for you `htdocs` folder for instance. When you then try to set new directives for you `vhost` it would remember that this is not permitted as per the main `.conf` file. So try to change that in you maninb conf file and see if it starts working. Remember to restart your webserver so it rereads the config file.

Comment: Hi Inquam, it's now got a new error reporting that it cant read the .htaccess file. So I put the file back in and made sure it has read permissions, but it's still complaining about the same problem. Restarted server after each change.   Don't know if it's related, but these files are sitting in a subdirectory of Dropbox, and I think I've had issues with file permissions in the past due to Dropbox.

Comment: Is it looking for the  `.htaccess` in the correct place? Skip the `.htaccess` and put in a fake `index.html` and see if reach it. Otherwise there might be an issue with you paths or something.

Comment: Interesting. I copied the files out of Dropbox, adjusted the paths in virtualhosts, and it now works. Minus one for Dropbox.

Comment: Yea Dropbox can screw thing up unfortunately. Glad it works for you ;)

Comment: Yes well thank you for pointing out the contributing problem with the change in the main conf file as well!

Comment: Done! Sorry thought i had, but I'd only done the vote up. ; )