# Deploy Django on Apache - Directory layout

Tags: django, apache, virtualhost

I have a Django application with the following directory structure

```
/myapp/
   /login/
   /myapp_settings/
   /subapp1/
   /supapp2/
```

`manage.py` is in the `myapp` directory.

In the project's `url.py` I have URL settings like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^subapp1/', include('subapp1.urls')),
    url(r'^xhr/', include('subapp1.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^subapp2/', include('smart_selects.urls')),

        # Login / logout.
    url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', {'next_page': '/subapp1/'}, name='auth_logout'),
    url(r'^logout/(?P<next_page>.*)/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', name='auth_logout_next'),
)
```

When deployed on the development `runserver`, everything links and loads correctly. When I deploy the entire `myapp` directory to the Django root on Apache, I find it's not linking as expected.

For example, if I link to `example.com/login/`, I get an Apache 404. I think it's because I don't have a virtual directory configuration defined for that specific directory.

I have the following set up in Apache for my application:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /myapp /var/www/django-projects/myapp/myapp_settings/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/django-projects/myapp

Alias /media/ /var/www/django-projects/myapp/media/
Alias /static/ /var/www/django-projects/myapp/static/


<Directory /var/www/django-projects/myapp/static>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/django-projects/myapp/media>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/django-projects/myapp/myapp_settings/>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
```

Do I need an Alias and a Directory configuration for each URL pattern I use? If so, how can I redo my URL patterns so that I don't need to do this. I don't want to have to do all of this extra Apache configuration when I deploy the application.

**EDIT:** I modified my `WSGIScriptAlias` as suggest by Reinbach. It now reads `WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/django-projects/myapp/myapp_settings/wsgi.py`. However, this still returns a 404. The error in the Apache log says

`[Fri Sep 07 09:11:00 2012] [error] [client 192.189.x.x] File does not exist: /var/www/html/login`

Notice that it's looking in `/var/www/html` (Default Apache root) instead of `/var/www/django-projects`

**EDIT2:** I'm attaching the VirtualHost block for this section

```
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/django-projects/myapp
<VirtualHost sub.example.com:80>
     DocumentRoot /var/www/django-projects/myapp
     ServerName sub.example.com
     WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/django-projects/myapp/myapp_settings/wsgi.py


     Alias /robots.txt /var/www/django-projects/myapp/static/robots.txt
     Alias /favicon.ico /var/www/django-projects/myapp/static/favicon.ico
     AliasMatch ^/([^/]*\.css) /var/www/django-projects/myapp/static/css/$1
     AliasMatch ^/([^/]*\.js) /var/www/django-projects/myapp/static/js/$1
     AliasMatch ^/([^/]*\.png) /var/www/django-projects/myapp/static/images/$1
     AliasMatch ^/([^/]*\.swf) /var/www/django-projects/myapp/static/swf/$1


     Alias /media/ /var/www/django-projects/myapp/media/
     Alias /static/ /var/www/django-projects/myapp/static/

     <Directory /var/www/django-projects/myapp/static>
         Order deny,allow
         Allow from all
     </Directory>
     <Directory /var/www/django-projects/myapp/media>
         Order deny,allow
         Allow from all
     </Directory>
     <Directory /var/www/django-projects/myapp/myapp_settings/>
         <Files wsgi.py>
              Order deny,allow
              Allow from all
         </Files>
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you want to change your WSGIScriptAlias as you currently have it expecting to handle `example.com/myapp/login` while your sample is showing you trying to use `example.com/login`

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/django-projects/myapp/myapp_settings/wsgi.py
```

See [How to use Django with Apache and mod_wsgi](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/)

Comment: you will need to define a VirtualHost for this application and then set the  "DocumentRoot /var/www/django-projects/myapp"

Answer (score 2):

**LONG STORY SHORT**

Allow and Deny are deprecated since Apache 2.4.x, use Require all granted (or denied) instead.

**THE LONG STORY**

I'm encountering the same problem while trying to set up Django with Apache and mod_wsgi. I'm not entirely sure why this happens but when I comment out the following lines in the httpd.conf

```
# Deny access to the entirety of your server's filesystem. You must
# explicitly permit access to web content directories in other 
# <Directory> blocks below.
#
#<Directory />
#    AllowOverride none
#    Require all denied
#</Directory>
```

everything works alright.

I'm not sure if this is the right and secure way to solve the problem, but I hope it might help.

**P.S.** I think this *shouldn't* cause much security troubles since root directory is aliased anyways:`WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/django-projects/myapp/myapp_settings/wsgi.py`, but I may be worng.

**P.P.S.** Looks like the better solution would be to leave those lines uncommented, but change Order and Allow directives in favor of Require all granted. For example:

```
<Directory /var/www/django-projects/myapp/myapp_settings/>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
#Order deny,allow
#Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
```

However this is only a trial and error solution I could come up. I got no deep understanding why it works but Order and Allow doesn't.

**P.P.P.S** Oh, now I know what. Allow and Deny are deprecated since Apache 2.4.x. Good answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11993187/1906174).