# Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

All I wanted to do today was to write a redirect rule to a subfolder, e.g.:
You enter the URL: **example.com** and you get redirected to **example.com/subfolder**

Such a simple wish. I tried to find a solution on the internet. The internet told me to add an **.htaccess** file in the htdocs root with:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ subfolder [L]
```

I did this. But no success obviously, they didn't told me I had to uncomment the module in **httpd.conf**:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

So I did this too. No success again. They didn't told me I had to change my **httpd.conf** so that the **.htaccess** file would be enabled:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/htdocs"
<Directory "c:/Apache24/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Again no success, because I get this error when entering the URL:

> Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Now I'm stuck and I couldn't find any more solutions on the internet. I'm just running Apache 2.4 on my Windows 7 machine, for private reasons.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apache permission denied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11992466/apache-permission-denied)

Comment: Where can i find the httpd.conf on apache2.4?

Answer (score 171, accepted):

Found my solution thanks to [Error with .htaccess and mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12140559/error-with-htaccess-and-mod-rewrite)
For **Apache 2.4** and in all *.conf files (e.g. httpd-vhosts.conf, http.conf, httpd-autoindex.conf ..etc) use

```
Require all granted
```

instead of

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

The *Order* and *Allow* directives are deprecated in **Apache 2.4**.

Comment: holy hell, just migrated from centos and i'm super glad i saw this.  Thank you!

Comment: Damn Deprecation! - Apache error message would have been nice

Comment: yes, totally aggree with @AndrewAtkinson. years of apache2, and now, same version, different config.

Comment: Thank you! The default magento 1.9.1 .htaccess used the deprecated way.

Comment: Sorry to ask but where exactly should we put that line?

Comment: I'm probably going to leave on work time now thanks to this. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks! In my case it was /etc/apache2/conf-available/security.conf that was denying the access.

Answer (score 12):

WORKING Method { if there is no problem other than configuration }

By Default Appache is **not restricting access** from ipv4. (common external ip)

**What may restrict is the configurations in 'httpd.conf' (or 'apache2.conf' depending on your apache configuration)**

Solution:

Replace all:

```
<Directory />
     AllowOverride none
    Require all denied

</Directory>
```

with

```
<Directory />
     AllowOverride none
#    Require all denied

</Directory>
```

hence removing out all restriction given to Apache

Replace `Require local` with  `Require all granted` at `C:/wamp/www/` directory

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
#   Require local
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 3):

Solution is just simple.

If you are trying to access server using your local IP address and you are getting error saying like **Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server**

Just open your httpd.conf file from (in my case `C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.2.21/conf/httpd.conf`)

Search for

`<Directory "D:/wamp/www/">
....
.....
</Directory>`

Replace 
**Allow from 127.0.0.1**

to

**Allow from all**

Save changes and restart your server.

Now you can access your server using your IP address

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in https.conf file!

```
# Virtual hosts
# Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

The error occurs when hash(#) is removed or messed around with. These two lines should appear as shown above.

Comment: Please format your answer.

Comment: messed around with what?

Answer (score 1):

Found my solution on Apache/2.2.15 (Unix).

And Thanks for answer from @QuantumHive:

First:
I finded all

```
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
```

instead of

```
Order allow,deny

Allow from all
```

and then:

I setted

```
#
# Control access to UserDir directories.  The following is an example
# for a site where these directories are restricted to read-only.
#
#<Directory /var/www/html>
#    AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#    Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
#    <Limit GET POST OPTIONS>
#        Order allow,deny
#        Allow from all
#    </Limit>
#    <LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS>
#        Order deny,allow
#        Deny from all
#    </LimitExcept>
#</Directory>
```

Remove the previous "#" annotation to

```
#
# Control access to UserDir directories.  The following is an example
# for a site where these directories are restricted to read-only.
#
<Directory /var/www/html>
    AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
    <Limit GET POST OPTIONS>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Limit>
    <LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS>
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
    </LimitExcept>
</Directory>
```

ps. my WebDir is: /var/www/html

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on Mac OS Mojave:

```
<Directory "/Users/{USERNAME}/Sites/project">
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    require all granted
</Directory>
```