# Mod_perl 2.0.9 in Yosemite Apache 2.4 does not execute .pl scripts

Tags: mod-perl, apache2.4

I've followed the clear and excellent procedure in [How to install mod_perl 2.0.9 in Apache 2.4 on OS X Yosemite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26483724/how-to-install-mod-perl-2-0-9-in-apache-2-4-on-os-x-yosemite) and installed mod_perl 2.0.9 in my Yosemite Apache 2.4. It compiled and installed without errors (a few warnings flew by during the compilation) and mod_perl/2.0.9dev Perl/v5.18.2 shows up in /server-status and with the apachectl command to list loaded modules.

But the perl scripts in my /Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables directory, which worked perfectly in previous versions of MacOS and Apache, do not execute. Instead, the source of the .pl file is displayed in the browser. Do I need some additional directives or other changes in /etc/spache2/httpd.conf? Are there steps I can/should take to debug this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had forgotten to enable mod_cgi.so. Did that and all is well.