# How to install mod_perl 2.0.10 in Apache 2.4 on OS X El Capitan?

Tags: osx-elcapitan, apache2.4, mod-perl2, xcode7.1

Build problems with a completely new install of mod_perl.  Here are the versions of my software.

OS X El Capitan 10.11.  Recently upgraded from OS X Yosemite 10.10. 
Xcode 7.1. Apache 2.4.16.  This is the Apache version that was included with 10.11
mod_perl 2.0.10.  Downloaded from SVN.

chrisbtoo's answer to [how-to-install-mod-perl-2-0-9-in-apache-2-4-on-os-x-yosemite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26483724/how-to-install-mod-perl-2-0-9-in-apache-2-4-on-os-x-yosemite) allowed the build to begin.  make fails like this

> -c modperl_util.c && mv modperl_util.o modperl_util.lo modperl_util.c:636:20: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the
>   argument has type 'apr_size_t'
>         (aka 'unsigned long') [-Wformat]
>                      size, (apr_size_t)r->finfo.size, r->filename);
>                      ^~~~ modperl_util.c:636:26: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'apr_size_t'
>         (aka 'unsigned long') [-Wformat]
>                      size, (apr_size_t)r->finfo.size, r->filename);
>                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 2 warnings generated. modperl_util.c:636:20: warning: format specifies type 'int'
>   but the argument has type 'apr_size_t'
>         (aka 'unsigned long') [-Wformat]
>                      size, (apr_size_t)r->finfo.size, r->filename);
>                      ^~~~ modperl_util.c:636:26: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'apr_size_t'
>         (aka 'unsigned long') [-Wformat]
>                      size, (apr_size_t)r->finfo.size, r->filename);
>                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 2 warnings generated.

then again

> -c modperl_common_util.c && mv modperl_common_util.o modperl_common_util.lo modperl_common_util.c:57:53: warning:
>   incompatible pointer types initializing 'int
>         (*)(PerlInterpreter *, SV *, MAGIC *, SV *, const char *, I32)' with an expression of type
>         'int (PerlInterpreter *, SV *, MAGIC *, SV *, const char *, int)'
>         [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
>                                                       modperl_table_magic_copy};
>                                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 1 warning generated.

then 68 duplicate symbol messages like this brief sample:

duplicate symbol _MP_vtbl_env in:

- mod_perl.lo
- modperl_interp.lo

duplicate symbol _MP_vtbl_envelem in:

- mod_perl.lo
- modperl_interp.lo

Here are the final error messages.

> make[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26483724/how-to-install-mod-perl-2-0-9-in-apache-2-4-on-os-x-yosemite): *** [mod_perl.so] Error 1 make: *** [modperl_lib] Error 2

Does this seem like anything in the environment that I might fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked for me was checking out codes from one of the tagged branches instead of checking out direct from the trunk.

The tagged branch I used: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/perl/modperl/tags/2_0_9/

so the first step then becomes:
svn checkout https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/perl/modperl/tags/2_0_9/ mod_perl-2.0

So just replace this step and then follow the rest of the steps in the link you used (ie [How to install mod_perl 2.0.9 in Apache 2.4 on OS X Yosemite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26483724/how-to-install-mod-perl-2-0-9-in-apache-2-4-on-os-x-yosemite)).

Comment: Many thanks @allkenang.  That seems to have worked.  The build, using the mod_perl branch you suggested, still generated 3 warnings but the install was allowed to complete.

Comment: More info for anyone who in the future happens upon this dialog.  The errors I saw likely relate to the changes introduced in Apache 2.4+, changes which mod_perl 2.0 development has not yet fully accommodated.