# Apache you don't have permissions to access / on this server already added Require all granted

Tags: apache

I have an Apache server that is giving me this popular error. I already tried adding "Require all granted" as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21551840/forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server) answer suggests. What else could it be?

My `httpd.conf` file has this:

```
<Directory >
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And I also tried doing `chmod 755` on the directory folder. I ran out of ideas. What else could it be? If you need anything other, please ask. Any advice will help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the directory to which the rules apply. It should be something like:

```
<Directory "/">
</Directory >
```

or

```
<Directory "/www/" >
</Directory>
```

See the syntax of the "Directory" directive here: [< Directory > Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory)