# By default, mobile browsers use HTTPS. How can I force mobile browers(Chrome and Firefox) to use HTTP?

Tags: android, http, mobile, browser, localhost

I have a web applicaton hosted on my laptop which does not use encryption. The site works fine when accessed from laptop browsers. When I try to access same(using IP-ADDRESS/site-name or http://IP-ADDRESS/site-name) using Firefox and Chrome from mobile, I get a warning stating that the local site is not secure. I bypassed the warning and tried to access the site but, both browsers still try to connect to the site over HTTPS and report an error that requested page does not exist.

By default, mobile browsers(Firefox and Chrome) are using HTTPS. How can I force mobile browsers to use HTTP?

Note:

1. Both browsers do not have plugins which force HTTPS usage.
2. I tried clearing cache but, both browsers still try to connect to the site over HTTPS and report an error that requested page does not exist.
3. Closed, re-opened browsers and re-tried site access but, result is same as above.

Comment: On wich Andoid version is this?

Comment: I suppose the problem is not with Android, as a web application(though different) worked earlier.