# how do i fix an 403 forbidden message in my Php document, that is linked to mysql?

Tags: apache, http-status-code-403

> Hello!
>   this is schoolwork, so it is probaly a very simple mistake. as i am a beginner, with basic knowledge i would really apreciate getting a straightfoward and easy answer:) thanks in advance!
>
> the Document i started with

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

<?php

$tjener = "localhost";
$brukernavn = "root";
$passord= "";
$database= "testfjell";

$kobling = new mysqli($tjener, $brukernavn, $passord, $database);

if ($kobling-> connect_error) {
  die("noe gikk galt med koblingen ". connect_error);
  // code...
}
else {
//  echo "koblingen kjører!";
}
$kobling->set_charset("utf8");

$sql= "SELECT * FROM fjell";
$resultat = $kobling->query($sql);

echo "<form method='post' action='endretilfjelltest.php>'";
while ($rad=$resultat-> fetch_assoc()) {
$fjell_id = $rad["fjell_id"];
$fjell= $rad["fjell"];
echo "<br>";
echo "  $fjell ";

echo "<input type= 'hidden' name= 'endre_id value='$fjell_id'>";
echo "<input type= 'submit' name='endre' value= 'endre'";

}
echo "</form>";
 ?>


  </body>
</html>
```

> the document i thought were going to appear

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

<?php
if(isset($_POST["endre_id"])){
  $endre_id=$_POST["endre_id"]

$tjener = "localhost";
$brukernavn = "root";
$passord= " ";
$database= "testfjell";

$kobling = new mysqli($tjener, $brukernavn, $passord, $database);

if ($kobling-> connect_error) {
  die("noe gikk galt med koblingen ". connect_error);
  // code...
}
$kobling->set_charset("utf8");

}
else {
  die("du må angi et fjell")
}

$sql= "SELECT * FROM fjell WHERE fjell_id = '$endre_id'";
$resultat= $kobling->query($sql);

echo "<form action= 'endre3fjell.php' method='POST'";
while($rad=$resultat->fetch_assoc()){
  $fjell_id=$rad["fjell_id"];
  $fjell=$rad["fjell"];

  echo "ID";
  echo "<input type='number' name='fjell_id' value = '$fjell_id' disabled>";
  echo "FJELL";
  echo "<input type= 'text' name='nyttfjell' value= '$fjell'>";
}

echo "<input type= 'submit' name='endre' value='endre>'"
echo "</form>";

 ?>


  </body>
</html>
```

> the message i got i google chrome :

**Forbidden**
*You don't have permission to access /endretilfjelltest.php> on this server.
Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 80*

> i do not have a teacher, and are trying to understand it by myself. I woul really apreciate if you would take a moment to help me out!
>   **thanks again:)**

Comment: _Small Note_ PHP5.5.12 is a little out of date now, [See the Supported Version](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php)

Comment: You also have a small typo here `name= 'endre_id` that shoudl be `name= 'endre_id'`

Comment: _Small Note_ If you want to echo a scalar variable in PHP `echo $fjell;` will do. You dont have to wrap it in double quotes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21551840/forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server)

Answer (score 2):

The error message has nothing to do with PHP. Your webserver (Apache) is telling you that
either the user account under which the server is running does not have access to the file "endretilfjelltest.php" or the file "endretilfjelltest.php" does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

> Thank You!
>   I figured it out, i had simply written

```
echo "<form method='post' action='endretilfjelltest.php>'";
```

> instead of

`echo "<form method='post' action='endretilfjelltest.php'>";`