# Xampp virtual host - access denied

Tags: xampp, apache

I'm running a XAMPP server on my laptop and I'm trying to setup a virtual host.

My hosts-file looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1      localhost
127.0.0.1      localhost.com
127.0.0.1      ehc.local
127.0.0.1      bal.local
```

The httpd-vhosts.conf file looks like this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost ehc.local:80>
   DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/EHC/src/main/php/www"
   ServerName ehc.local
   SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "local"

   <Directory "C:/wamp/EHC/src/main/php/www">
      Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
   </Directory>
   ErrorLog "logs/ehc.dev-error_log"
   CustomLog "logs/ehc.dev-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

When I browse to 'ehc.local', I only get the default 403-error page.

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

*This is for osx but must be the same (or similar) in windows:*

Because Apache runs as the ‘nobody’ user by default, it may not have adequate permission to browse your [OSX/Win] user directory or some of its subdirectories, in which case you’ll see a 403 ‘access forbidden’ error when you try and view your development site. Similarly, you may find that although you can view your dev site, PHP throws errors when you attempt to write files or make directories on the filesystem.

To fix this you can configure Apache to run as your [OSX/Win] user. Open httpd.conf and look for the following lines:

```
# User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
# It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
# running httpd, as with most system services.
#
User nobody
Group nogroup
```

Change User to your [OSX/Win] username, and save the file:

```
User yourusername
```

Restart Apache and you should now be able to navigate your site without any issues, including manipulating files and folders using PHP.

[Source](http://f6design.com/journal/2012/03/11/configuring-virtualhosts-in-xampp-on-mac/)

I Hope it will be helpful, Greetings!

Answer (score 7):

Changing user didn't work.
For me it was this answer that did the trick:
[Adding VirtualHost fails: Access Forbidden Error 403 (XAMPP) (Windows 7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110179/adding-virtualhost-fails-access-forbidden-error-403-xampp-windows-7)

Just add `Require all granted` to your `<Directory>` setup and it should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

you should try this:

-> go to XAMPP folder,

-> open apache-conf-extra folder

-> open httpd-xampp.conf with the text-editor of your choice

Scroll all the way down until you find `Deny from all` and change that too `Allow from all`

Comment: 13:56:00  [Apache]  Attempting to start Apache app...
13:56:00  [Apache]  Status change detected: running
13:56:01  [Apache]  Status change detected: stopped
13:56:01  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
13:56:01  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
13:56:01  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
13:56:01  [Apache]  Check the "/xampp/apache/logs/error.log" file
13:56:01  [Apache]  and the Windows Event Viewer for more clues