# how to access local webserver

Tags: apache, lan

I have an apache server, which I want to access from another pc at home. when I access it by using ip address, it show http 403 error. I can ping the web server and I turned off the firewall from the web server. And there  is restrict ip address in the apache config. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your log and apache configuration

Do you add this line

```
Require all granted
```

In your configuration?

Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110179/adding-virtualhost-fails-access-forbidden-error-403-xampp-windows-7) will solve your problem,