# Apache server 2.4.9 error number 403

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel-4

I'm having a problem with Apache server 2.4.9 error number `403`.

i've been trying to fix it on my own using all this solutions:

1. Options +Indexes in `.htaccess` file.
2. changing the default in `httpd.conf`.
3. `chmod +775` www folder.
4. changing the hosts file in `windows/system32`

Here is my configuration in `httpd.conf`:

```
Require all granted
```

And the httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
Require all granted
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding VirtualHost fails: Access Forbidden Error 403 (XAMPP) (Windows 7)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110179/adding-virtualhost-fails-access-forbidden-error-403-xampp-windows-7)

Comment: it's the only thing in the <Directory></Directory>

Comment: What does the apache error log say? Check the last line of error log after loading the page with 403 error.

Answer (score 0):

Add the "require all granted" in your vhost configuration inside the directory.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    HostName test.test.de
    DocumentRoot /var/www/xxx/

    <Directory /var/www/xxx>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

[Adding VirtualHost fails: Access Forbidden Error 403 (XAMPP) (Windows 7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110179/adding-virtualhost-fails-access-forbidden-error-403-xampp-windows-7)