# How To Set Up Apache Virtual Hosts on XAMPP (Windows)

Tags: xampp

How To Set Up Apache Virtual Hosts on XAMPP (Windows)

Comment: Awesome, looks like this is it. Do I just add the tag to the existing two or do I overwrite?

Comment: I'd like to configure my vhosts for a project, if possible. As according to this CMS documentation: http://nnb.geomash.com/documentation/1.6/basic-installation/webserver-configuration

Comment: ok here is what I understand; you have XAMPP installed with apache webserver and you want to create seperate virtual host to an application; 

let say your main webserver is http://locahost and your new application is http://cms.localhsot? is that correct

Comment: From my understanding, vhosts is used to run multiple domains on the same machine. This is what I want to achieve. Plus, the documentation tutorials tells you to do it (which makes me think it'll come handy at some point, even if I don't know it right now).

Answer (score 118):

You need to follow some steps to create a virtual host in windows with apache.

> **Note:** To start with, the only difference for this guideline, between XAMPP and WAMP or other Apache packages for Windows, is a question about where those packages are installed on your computer.

**Introduction:** vhost (virtual host) is a great solution if you intend to develop many independent projects in PHP and keep them isolated from each other, like:

- Project 1 is based on PHP and has the local URL address `php.localhost`
- Project 2 is a Laravel project with URL `laravel.localhost`
- Project 3 is a Codeigniter with URL `codeigniter.localhost`
- Project 4 is a WordPress with URL `wordpress.localhost`

You are expected to have installed the latest version of XAMPP/WAMP. Btw, in my case, I have only installed Apache and MySQL.

> ***Note:** By default, most web servers will use port 80 as the default port, in some situations if you have another web server installed like (Microsoft IIS), it uses port 80 as well OR in other cases, SKYPE does also sometimes use port 80 like it is the case for some in Windows 8/10 for some users, in that case, you can do two thing’s

- Change your Apache port to port `8080`, `8081` etc., or some other free ports (note: 8080 can sometimes also give some problems)
- OR Change your other software/IIS port and keep Apache to default port 80 in case of Skype, just kill the Skype app and restart it after installing Apache on port 80, and Skype will automatically get a new port.

I have chosen to change my Apache to **port 8080**.

> **Note:**

- For the next section, we need to use a text editor like notepad or regular IDE. I used a sublime text editor.
- If you keep Apache to default port 80, skip this part and move on to Virtual hosts

**Change XAMPP/WAMP port (only if necessary)**
*if left default, then jump to Setting virtual host*

**Step 1. Edit httpd.conf**

Click on Config -> Apache (httpd.conf)
Or you find the file here `C:\XAMPP\apache\conf\httpd.conf`, `C:\XAMPP\apache2\conf\httpd.conf`, `C:\Bitnami\wampstack\apache\conf\httpd.conf` or `C:\Bitnami\wampstack\apache2\conf\httpd.conf` or similar location.

Change the line with

```
Listen 80
```

To 8080 or other, free ports.

```
Listen 8080
```

While we have `httpd.conf` file open we need to ensure that `httpd-vhosts.conf` is included:
`Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

### Virtual hosts

> **Note:** By default server documents are located on `C:\XAMPP\htdocs` or `C:\Bitnami\wampstack\apache2\htdocs` that’s fine if you have only one project or many small test files. However, if you need to develop many projects then it suggested separating them by the virtual host, as mentioned earlier.

**Step 2. Setting Virtual host**

1. Create a folder for your projects; I have created one in `c:\vhost` you can call it projects etc.
2. In `c:\vhost` folder we create a sub-folder domain1 or project1 or any other, it is up to you (`c:\vhost\project1`)
3. Open `httpd-vhosts.conf` file `C:\XAMPP\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf` Add the following code in line depending on how many vhost you want to create:

```
<Directory C:/vhost>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#this is the default address of XAMPP    
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot "C:/XAMPP/htdocs/"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

#this is the first vhost address in XAMPP
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot "C:/vhost/project1/"
    ServerName php.localhost
    SetEnv NS_ENV variable_value
</VirtualHost>

#this is the second vhost address in XAMPP for project like Laravel
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot "C:/vhost/Laravel-Blog/public"
    ServerName laravel.localhost
</VirtualHost>

etc
```

> **Note:** If you work on Laravel projects you can create unlimited Laravel projects as well as other frameworks like CodeIgniter, Yii, etc., the point is to
> have your Laravel project/s on `c:\vhost\laravel1`,
> `c:\vhost\laravel2` etc and make `c:\vhost\laravel1\public` as
> DocumentRoot etc as shown before. Each Laravel project will have own
> VirtualHost URL.

Save and close the file

**Some additional information and notes:**

- If the port remains default 80 then the URL address will be `localhost`
- If the port remains default 80 then the VirtualHost tag should be changed to `<VirtualHost *:80>`
- If the port is changed to `8080`, the URL address will be `localhost:8080`
- And the vhost URL address could look like this `project1.localhost:8080` etc
- You can add unlimited projects and virtual hosts this way.

*We are not ready yet, read more.*

**Step 3. Edit Windows Host file**

1. Stop Apache and MySQL services from XAMPP/WAMP.
2. Open the hosts file in `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc`
   you need Administrator privilege to edit the file.
   I suggest editing the file directly with the Sublime text editor.
3. Add `127.0.0.1    project1.localhost` at the end of the file, and Save and close the file.

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       php.localhost
127.0.0.1       laravel.localhost
127.0.0.1       codeigniter.localhost
127.0.0.1       wordpress.localhost
127.0.0.1       laravel2.localhost
etc. those are just examples
```

save the file

**Final Step.**
Start/Re-start your Apache and MySQL again.

---

**Addition (Suggestion)**

> **Note:** Under your development process you might face a problem having a cache on because you can risk updating something in Laravel and it won't appear in your browser. Therefore you might need to disable PHP cache under the development process in your local environment.

Open file `php.ini` under PHP folder in your Apache (XAMPP or WAMP) folder and
change `opcache.enable` to `0` so it looks like this:

```
[opcache]
zend_extension=php_opcache.dll
; Determines if Zend OPCache is enabled
opcache.enable=0
```

---

**Addition (Alternative solution)**

> **Important:** The following solution is not suitable to test Restful Api, canvas, heavy solutions, etc.it might give you some headaches, so I would suggest a virtual host solution with port 80 as default.

It is possible to deploy a temporary Virtual Server without necessarily configuring XAMPP/WAMP Virtual Host, start the CMD console, and run the following PHP command:

```
php -S localhost:8001 -t c:\vhost\Laravel-Project\public
```

- Port 8001 can be changed to any available port number and be sure not to conflict with other software ports.
- `c:\vhost\Laravel...` path should be changed to whatever your project path.
- It is possible to start multiple servers but should have different port numbers.

In your browser, you need only to write

```
http://localhost:8001/
```

**Note on 403 Access forbidden error**

If you get a 403 Access forbidden error when you browse your site, you may need to add this to your httpd.conf file:

```
<Directory path_to_dir>
    AllowOverride none
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: If you get a 403 Access forbidden error when you browse to your site, you may need to add this to your httpd.conf file:

<Directory path_to_dir>
    AllowOverride none
    Require all granted
</Directory>

Comment: is there any way to get rid of the :8001 from the url? i mean can i make `http://local.xyz.com` point to `http://localhost:8001/xyz/public`?

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ yes i followed the guide and it is so awesome 
worked from the first try, thank you for that. my port 80 is also occupied by other stuff thats why i am using port 8989 so i was wondering if its possible not to write it in the url, like forcing it from the vhost config or the host file

Comment: @George as far as I know I do not think it is possible, that said I have never tried it before neither research this possibility. I have cousily just made a quick search on google and found link you can read https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/55123/can-dns-point-to-specific-port and

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ i just read the link you provided, it seems that it is not possible currently, so i will try to free port 80 since it will be easier than trying to achieve what i want, yes i am lazy :d, if i find more information on this topic i will link it here. thank you so much for the help and have a good day

Answer (score 2):

You can make your localhost to point to different folders on different port numbers. Follow these simple steps:

**Step 1:** Make your apache to listen to multiple ports. Go to C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf and search for the key word Listen you can see something like this Listen 80. Now tell your apache to listen to multiple ports, replace that with below content

- Listen 80
- Listen 8001
- Listen 8002

**Step 2:** Now go to “C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf”, this is the actual player. At the end of the file you can specify something like this below:

DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/project1"
ServerName localhost:8001

DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/project2"
ServerName localhost:8002

Which tells your apache to take different folders on hitting different port numbers. That is when you hit localhost:8001/ it will take the contents from project1, similarly localhost:8002/ will point to your project2 folder.

By doing this we and run 2 different sites on our local machine.

***Note:*** You need to restart your apache whenever you change something in httpd.conf or httpd-vhosts.conf.

Comment: A note for other people: remember to use <VirtualHost *:8001> and <VirtualHost *:8002>, respectively!

Answer (score 1):

Virtual Host create

1. C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra 
   Open httpd-vhost file then 
   Add
       
               DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\project\timegrid\public"
            ServerName mytimegrid.me(ur choice)
2. C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
       Open hosts file then add   127.0.0.1       mytimegrid.me(Your Domain Name)

N.B. you first open your editor(notepad etc....) as Run As Administrator mode otherwise you can not save these files. ok.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, open your Notepad as an Administrator and 
then click on `file > open`. Then go to your window driver now search for `system32` folder and then search for `drivers` folder and then the `etc` folder.

Now you'll see a folder of empty files, so don't worry to see Text Documents (`*.txt`) at the bottom. Change the view to `all files` and then you will see the `vhost` file.

Open and enjoy!

Comment: You call this an answer?