# Laravel PHP: multiple project run at the same time

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-5, localhost

I want to run multiple laravel frame work project at the same time.Exactly how to do it I dont know.

I used a command :      php artisan serv --port=8080 , to run another project at port 8080.
when I use this command into the cmd it shows the error:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks to me like you need to run

```
$ composer install
```

As Laravel cannot find composers autoloader.

Another thing, with your tags, if you're using Laravel 5, then you should now L5 doesn't come with the serve command anymore. Laravel is pushing Homestead, and you should be moving to Homestead for your local development anyhow.

If you'd rather stick with your PHP installation, use the following command to do that:

```
$ php -S localhost:8080 -t public
```

One last thing, the server option in L4's artisan is spelled "serve"

Comment: Thanks for your answer , i also solved the problem using:$  php atrisan serve --port="88"

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad you were able to get it working. However, my stance on L4's built in server initializer. It's best to get into the Homestead environment. I recommend taking a look at it: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead

Comment: I have asked another question Can u help me??? here is the link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28059433/autocomplete-text-field-in-laravel-using-database

Comment: How about virtual host you could follow this link if so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754367/how-to-setting-up-virtual-hosts-for-xampp-on-windows-full-guideline/27754990#27754990

Answer (score 14):

**1st project**

```
php artisan serve
```

it will automatically assign port *`8000`* as *`http://127.0.0.1:8000`*

**2nd project** at the same time should be on different port *`8080`* like following

```
php artisan serve --port=8080
```

you can run "n" number of projects on different ports.

Comment: I want to know where to configure the port number in ubnutu 20.04 VM?

Answer (score 3):

there is an error in your command. just use ***php artisan serve --port=8080***. And if the port is running for any other application keep on trying another port number instead of **8080**