# Laravel 5 error.

Tags: php, laravel

I just uploaded my L5 project to host server. And this is the error that I'm getting.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CLASS, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '$' on line 50 this line is in index.php

This is the 50 line

```
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);
```

Can I somehow change this line or make my project to php 5.5.32 version ? Because L5 framework using 5.6.25 and that sucks a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

```
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);//This is line 50
```

the `::class` is only supported since PHP 5.5

Ref:[Laravel 4 inside Wamp does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30767080/laravel-4-inside-wamp-does-not-work)

Requirement:

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/releases#laravel-5.1.4

Comment: ok, my host is using 5.5.32 I heard that L5 required 5.5.9 is it true ? My project is written in 5.6

Comment: Laravel 5.1 requires PHP 5.5.9 or greater. ref:http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/releases#laravel-5.1.4

Comment: Is there are anyway to make this project on 5.5.32 without deleting all files ?

Comment: @feknaz. no idea regarding that