# How to upload laravel 5.0 project on server

Tags: laravel

I need to upload laravel 5.0 project on server, my problem is how to upload without composer on server and run properly project.

Comment: Do u want to upload it on share hosting or forge? If it's share hosting, check my answer bellow

Comment: "how to upload without composer" uhhhmm you know like we have done for years? ftp, rsync, whatever tool

Comment: in addition to Michel, Follow this guideline and you can create unlimited laravel projects on your xampp web server http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754367/how-do-i-set-up-my-apache-virtualhost-settings-with-xampp-on-windows/27754990#27754990'

Answer (score 0):

Put the content of your public folder (Laravel public folder) in public_html. 
Then any other files and folders upload them in your root directory:

So your folder structure will look something like this:

Remote server:

```
--App
  bootstrap
  Vendors
  artisan
  etc...
--public_html
            |
            |
            --css
              img
              index.php
              .htaccess
              etc...
```

On localhost without composer:

Your Laravel project folder should be in www folder (if wampp server) or htdocs (xampp) and with this `localhost/laravelProject/public` your project should work.

Comment: And how to run laravel 5.0 project on localhost without php artisan serve

Answer (score 0):

You can copy all file form public to root folder or use a htacess file to point main doain to public folder.
[Check this article](http://sauravkc.com.np/blog/laravel-in-shared-hosting) it might help.