# Accessing Virtual Host Name (xampp) on network returns 404 error

Tags: apache, xampp, virtualhost

I want to access virtual host on network with other devices. I set the Apache's Virtual Host using xampp like this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/site_mobile"
    ServerName site.mobile
    <Directory "D:/xampp/htdocs/site_mobile">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI    
    AllowOverride All
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And this is how I access the Servername in network:

```
192.168.1.102/site.mobile/
```

Unfortunately, I get an error considering

> Object not found!
>   The Requested URL was not found on this server...

Accessing the path and not the ServerName works fine on my own device and on the network:

```
localhost/site_mobile/
192.168.1.102/site_mobile/
```

**I have to mention that accessing only `site.mobile` on my own device works fine**

Comment: Other devices on your network are not aware of any local names you specify on your Xampp machine. It's too long of a story to explain in a comment, but basically it comes down to the DNS lookup that needs to be done. You would have to setup a DNS server in your local network and have all devices use that in order for this to work. It's probably more hassle than it's worth.

Comment: is `site.mobile` vs `site_mobile` just a typo in your example or in your configuration / attempts too ?

Comment: @Oldskool where do you think he uses something relevant to DNS (besides the config file) ? At least the connection attempts listed in the question all use an ip address

Comment: @Marged No. `site_mobile` is the path I am using to access the files on the browser. The URL in that form in my own device is: `localhost/site_mobile/` and of course I can access this path on the network using device's IP address like this: `192.168.1.102/site_mobile/`
But, when there comes to set a virtual host name for this path, I can access `site.mobile` on my own device on the browser, but, accessing it on the network using the IP doesn't work.

Comment: I encourage you to look at this guideline, it is tested and working. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754367/how-do-i-set-up-my-apache-virtualhost-settings-with-xampp-on-windows/27754990#27754990