# How to setup existing yii project in xampp on windows

Tags: php, yii

I have yii framework project in server its running successfully.

but let me know how its setup xammp server(local) on windows.
checked my self in this way:

1. Changed php.exe file path local server path.
2. Changed environmental variables also
3. Run like this http://127.0.0.1/html and http://localhost/html

but its always says Object Not Found
please suggest the procedure .

Comment: please follow this generic guideline, it is also tested for Yii with small changes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754367/how-do-i-set-up-my-apache-virtualhost-settings-with-xampp-on-windows/27754990#27754990

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your [.htaccess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.htaccess) file. Default file content:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /connect_donors
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```