# Laravel 5.1 upload on host

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have used the **Laravel 5.1 php framework** to build a web application on my *local XAMPP server*.

1. Which files or folders should be uploaded on my shared host server?
2. Should the `.env` file at the root be uploaded?
3. In this case, if sensitive information such as database connection passwords are in this file, is there a security risk?

Comment: @maytham : Which settings are required to protect this file in local Xampp server?

Comment: tnx, all files in root must be protected from access?

Comment: when i go to http://localhost/laravel/.env in browser show all sensitive information  in this file

Comment: no i dont use   nginx, i use apache

Comment: tnx, before upload in share host, how protect .env  in local xampp server?

Comment: ok, @ali when you upload in root it will be automatically protected you do not need to do any thing, but 2 problems 1. your xampp config is wrong, 2. shared solution is not the best way to go.. Any way here is my suggestion, follow the instruction I made for your local xampp. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754367/how-do-i-set-up-my-apache-virtualhost-settings-with-xampp-on-windows/27754990#27754990 and this will help you understand how Laravel folder/file structure works, then you wont have problem understanding what I mean regarding your shared host etc.

Comment: When you done with xampp setup, let me know so I can make you a full guide line for how to do it in VPS solution, shared solution will only work if your host provider make the changes for you. that I do not suggest and do not know if they allow that, you need to ask them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. All project files should be uploaded under project root `\var\www\project` (project = all laravel project folder and files and `\var\www\project\public` is where your domain pointing.
   Storage should have write permission.
2. `.env` will be under project root and it is not available for public access.
3. `.env` won't be accessible for public, if it is then you have a configuration problem with you web server.

Comment: hi maytham. I did all the configuration as you said in live server. I pasted .env file in root level. Even though I faced server 500 error. what is the reason for this?

Comment: Hi @sankaran, which host type do you have

Comment: it is a free hosting site. I got an answer maytham. PHP version is lower.

Answer (score 2):

Move All the files on **xyz(your folder name for which domain/subdomain is mapped)** folder

Then follow these steps

1. Go to public folder
2. Copy .htacsses file
3. Paste it in **xyz** folder
4. Change server.php to index.php
5. Enjoy and happy coding

This is working fine with hostgator.in shared hosting.