# How to host Laravel 5.1 in live server

Tags: php, webserver, laravel-5.1, web-deployment

I took larave 5.1 framework and created my own simple project. It is working fine in localhost.

I try to move on free hosting live server(byethost.com - php version > 5.4). But I don't know how to deploy in live server.

I go through some documentation. So that I moved all file to public_html folder. Then transfer public_html/public files into public_html folder. change file path in index.php.

Even though I did not see any proper output. Whether I have to any additional configuration?  Please help me.

Note: I faced server 500 error.! what is the exact reason for this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.1 upload on host](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31113042/laravel-5-1-upload-on-host)

Answer (score 2):

First you have to upload all files (except `public` directory) in root directory. then upload all contents of `public` directory in server `public_html` directory. Then edit `server.php` file and replace all `public` to `public_html` like this

```
$uri = urldecode(
    parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)
);

// This file allows us to emulate Apache's "mod_rewrite" functionality from the
// built-in PHP web server. This provides a convenient way to test a Laravel
// application without having installed a "real" web server software here.
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public_html'.$uri)) {
    return false;
}

require_once __DIR__.'/public_html/index.php';
```

Remember laravel run with php version 5.5.9> . if your server does not fullfill the requirements it may not working fine.