# Virtual Host is not working on XAMPP

Tags: xampp

I just tried creating a virtual host on my local machine but when I try visiting the URL on my browser, instead it connects to the internet. I have put off my internet and tried but it still doesn't route to my site folder. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

BTW, I am using Apache 2.4

Here's my httpd-vhosts.conf code.

```
<directory C:/auth/public>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</directory>

<virtualhost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/auth/public"
    ServerName auth.local
</virtualhost>
```

And here is my hosts code.

```
#127.0.0.1      localhost
127.0.0.1       auth.local
#::1            localhost`
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I have made a complete guideline to VHOST for XAMPP in stackoverflow follow that and it should works http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754367/how-do-i-set-up-my-apache-virtualhost-settings-with-xampp-on-windows/27754990#27754990

Comment: Maytham, i have followed the instruction you have on the link you posted here but it still doesnt work..

Comment: try chaning your port til some thing else. and see if same problem occurs

Comment: I have changed my port severally. I dont have any program that uses my port..

Comment: if you are doing the right step and does not work it means that the problem is not from your xampp it must be some 3rd part software that might occurs the problem. Any how to be sure I suggest you to uninstall xampp and delete temp files belong to xampp, reinstall it i fresh and try the steps. Before you start the step try to see if XAMPP default page starts at all, and remember to make backup of your mysql database if you have data you need to keep

Comment: Have you got it to work?

Comment: It works after i changed <VirtualHost *:80> to <VirtualHost www.auth.localhost> and as well added it to my host.. Now the problem is, it takes me to Xampp welcome page.. instead of going into my application path  auth.localhost/public

Comment: Hmmm it very weird thing. what is your Operating system version. are you sure you do not have a software that makes conflict of what you doing, because I have never through a such scenario before.