# Installing php on windows and configuring with expression web 4?

Tags: php, web-services, web, expression-web, microsoft-expression-web

I am fairly new to using PHP. I am trying to use it with expression web 4. Any example I see online to install PHP is version 5.3.

PHP current version 5.6. Now using this http://windows.php.net/download/ I downloaded PHP. I downloaded zip of VC11 x86 Non Thread Safe. I extracted it. Copied to C:\. Then when I go to tools, advanced options in Expression web, I can point it to the php directory.

But when I am programming a .php file. I see the design window empty. Also when I actually open it with browser, it states it cannot open page.

What am I wrong or missing?

Comment: Will installing php throught this work with expression web 4?

Comment: I have no idea, I just lost my faith in Microsoft

Comment: Have you solved this issue

Comment: I did. I ended up downloading XAMPP, and abandoning expressoin web 4.

Comment: ;) so you understand why I suggested XAMPP :=

Comment: I have made a guideline here for virtual host so you can create unlimited project seperated from each other for xampp if you like it pls vote, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754367/how-to-setting-up-virtual-hosts-for-xampp-on-windows-full-guideline/27754990#27754990

Comment: Do you know how to add odbc or dblib to PDO drivers, so i can connect to sql database? I believe this only comes with mysql, sqlite PDO drivers.

Comment: I actually have never tried it before, typically I use myssql to php or mssql to c# mvc