# How to point server_x\laravel\submit as root in XAMPP?(windows)

Tags: xampp

I need to change it in order for the localhost to change its root directory. it will display the web page by default. I've tried changing the apache httpd.conf but then, apache doesn't run.

Comment: follow this guide line http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754367/how-to-setting-up-virtual-hosts-for-xampp-on-windows-full-guideline/27754990#27754990

Comment: Was the guideline usful?