# Laravel framework install failed on xampp

Tags: php, laravel

Hi guys when I install laravel framework with composer I have two errors. How can I solve this? Thanks in advance !

```
composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"
```

**Errors :**

```
 [RuntimeException]                                                                                                                                               


       Could not load package laravel/framework in http://packagist.org: 
    [UnexpectedValueException] 
        Could not parse version constraint ^1.0.4: Invalid version string "^1.0.4"
```

..

```
  [UnexpectedValueException]                                                  
  Could not parse version constraint ^1.0.4: Invalid version string "^1.0.4"
```

**

```
**Edited :**
composer diagnose
Checking composer.json: FAIL
name : The property name is required
description : The property description is required
No license specified, it is recommended to do so. For closed-source software you may use "proprietary" as license.
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking https connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking github.com rate limit: OK
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking composer version: OK
```

**

Comment: which version you want to install?

Comment: Did you try the alternative method they list on the manual page?  Where instead of using the installer you use composer?  composer create-project laravel/laravel test-laravel-5-project –prefer-dist

Comment: İt creates project  Andy. But it also gives same error

Comment: Btw if you want to make multiple Laravel projects of any version, I suggest you to make virtual host maybe it is worth it to look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754367/how-to-setting-up-virtual-hosts-for-xampp-on-windows-full-guideline/27754990#27754990 this works for windows os.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below command to install a new laravel project of a specific version

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel your_project_name 4.2.*
```

here **4.2.*** is the version

**Edit:**

Update your composer.

Comment: 5 mins ago i created a project with this. however let me check on this

Comment: i did search on this issue and it says you need to update your composer. So try doing it. @Revenge

Answer (score 1):

You can use below command:

```
composer self-update
```

and then create project like this:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel {you-project-name} 4.2 --prefer-dist
```