# Laravel server error

Tags: php, laravel

I've copied my laravel project from my pc to laptop. On my laptop I use xampp (mac). But when I've setup my server etc. with php artisan migrate I can't see my homepage it's just saying "server error".

When I look into my Apache log file it's telling me:

> Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable
>   configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the
>   limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

I guess I've to change something in my .htacces file? Please see the attached image for my folder structure.

[image]

EDIT:

.htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: we need more info.  Your apache configuration, your htaccess file, laravel app.config, any virtual host config

Comment: this is for setup xampp vhost in windows, try to follow it the process is the same in mac, it shows also how to setup vhost for laravel http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754367/how-to-setting-up-virtual-hosts-for-xampp-on-windows-full-guideline

Answer (score 0):

A couple things here:

- It looks like your laravel installation is at htdocs/public/. If so, your laravel installation is missing it's public directory.
- The installation at htdocs/public has no index.php or index.html file, that would result in an error as Apache doesn't know what file to return to the browser when navigating to that directory.

Your error could also be due to what you are navigating your browser to. Check the above bullet points first and see if they fix your errors.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But that isn't making the error here. I've made it like this so for example the .env file is not accessible. On my pc it's working this way. And my Apache gives an error in the log file.

Comment: Then you will need to give us more info. We will need at least the .htaccess file. And what URL are you trying to access the site at?

Comment: I'm trying to access the site on localhost. In my routes file I've this: Route::get('/','TicketsController@index'); I've added the .htacces file to my question ^.

Comment: Does your `index` method have any redirects in it? what directory is `localhost` pointing to?