# Laravel 5.2 in xampp object not found

Tags: laravel, xampp, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I asked before, I defined the route like this:

```
Route::get('error/{name}',function($name){
    return $name;
});
```

I can access other routes successfully. Only this one return `Object not found`.I have tried to solve this problem days. Today i found these code in xampp config file `/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf`:

```
Alias /error/ "E:/xampp/apache/error/"

<Directory "E:/xampp/apache/error">
    AllowOverride None
    Options IncludesNoExec
    AddOutputFilter Includes html
    AddHandler type-map var
    Require all granted
    LanguagePriority en cs de es fr it ja ko nl pl pt-br ro sv tr
    ForceLanguagePriority Prefer Fallback
</Directory>

ErrorDocument 400 /error/HTTP_BAD_REQUEST.html.var
ErrorDocument 401 /error/HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED.html.var
ErrorDocument 403 /error/HTTP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
ErrorDocument 404 /error/HTTP_NOT_FOUND.html.var
ErrorDocument 405 /error/HTTP_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED.html.var
ErrorDocument 408 /error/HTTP_REQUEST_TIME_OUT.html.var
ErrorDocument 410 /error/HTTP_GONE.html.var
ErrorDocument 411 /error/HTTP_LENGTH_REQUIRED.html.var
ErrorDocument 412 /error/HTTP_PRECONDITION_FAILED.html.var
ErrorDocument 413 /error/HTTP_REQUEST_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE.html.var
ErrorDocument 414 /error/HTTP_REQUEST_URI_TOO_LARGE.html.var
ErrorDocument 415 /error/HTTP_UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE.html.var
ErrorDocument 500 /error/HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.html.var
ErrorDocument 501 /error/HTTP_NOT_IMPLEMENTED.html.var
ErrorDocument 502 /error/HTTP_BAD_GATEWAY.html.var
ErrorDocument 503 /error/HTTP_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE.html.var
ErrorDocument 506 /error/HTTP_VARIANT_ALSO_VARIES.html.var
```

If I delete these code, my route works. So i have a problem, should i define my route not in `error` or give above code alias another name instead of `error`?

Comment: your route is not correct, try to put $name inside function($name)

Comment: I have just created it and works for me

Comment: sorry, i just missed it in the code.But my original code has `$name`

Comment: ok it works for me, are you working directly from xampp or do you have vhost?

Comment: I just asked this question in xampp forums. The manager replied me. There are some special urls in xampp. Here is the link: [special urls](https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=68998&p=236503#p236503)

Comment: But i have suggestions to you

Answer (score 0):

I was going to answer this question, but waited your response.

As you have discovered that XAMPP has default system [URL addresses](https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=68998&p=236503#p236503) as pr your comment.

It is because you are using XAMPP default folder for your production which is a bad practice.

I have tested your scenario in an virtual host XAMPP and it works with out problem, therefore to come over this challenge you need to configure you XAMPP virtual host.

Here is a [guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754367/how-to-setting-virtual-hosts-for-xampp-in-windows/27754990#27754990) you can follow and you will be able to have unlimited isolated projects.

This means you will be able to create `/error` directory with out having problem.