# Laravel 5.2: url not found but router is available in windows 7 wamp server

Tags: laravel-5, wamp

Default route is running

for example:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});
```

When i run this http://localhost/laracast/public
Shows outputs as LARAVEL 5

But when I add new route to

```
Route::get('/hello', function() {    
return 'Welcome to Laracast';
});
```

It shows output as => url not found

I am using

1.Windows7

2.Wamp Server

3.Composer and

4.GIT BASH

what the mistake i done it

Comment: I believe you have set it wrong up in your wamp, it is a good practice to make virtual host, follow this guide line and it should works. it si for xampp but it works for wamp as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754367/how-to-setting-virtual-hosts-for-xampp-in-windows/27754990#27754990

Comment: Did you use this http://localhost/laracast/public/ or http://localhost/laracast/public/hello ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are changing the default route to `/hello`, you need to make sure you visit `http://localhost/laracast/public/hello` in the browser.

If you are just trying to display your own message, change the default route to:

```
Route::get('/', function() {    
    return 'Welcome to Laracast';
});
```

i.e. remove `hello` from the route and it will correctly display your welcome message when visiting `http://localhost/laracast/public`