# Apache: Configuring Virtual host

Tags: virtualhost

i've been tinkering about codeigniter and trying to create a virtual host for the website but when i start and browse local.jpcs.com

it gives me a 404 Page not Found error

[image]

[image: this is the path im aiming]

This is the path im aiming the xampp/htdocs/jpcs

Comment: it gives me an error that says 404 Page not Found

Comment: Look at this guide http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754367/how-to-setting-virtual-hosts-for-xampp-in-windows/27754990#27754990

Answer (score 0):

Use forward slashes in your file paths.

Have you included vhosts in httpd.conf?

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Comment: ir redirects me to a link that says