# How can i select single file on localhost from htdocs folder in Php when htdocs folder contain multiple files

Tags: php, php-5.3

I have multiple files in htdocs folder in XAMMP but i cannot access any file 
instead of **index.php** file

if i want to access an other file from local host which is in htdocs folder i 
change the name of that file to **index.php** and than i write in URL "`localhost/projects`" than the file is accessible but any other file with other name i can not access or i don't know how to Access.

So, Please Guide me as i am new to Php.

Comment: you can access your file by typing its file location like this. if you have a `home.php` inside the `htdocs/test` folder you can type in `localhost/test/home.php`

Comment: Thanks man it works :) Really thanks

Comment: in long term it is better practices to have vhost, guideline here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754367/how-to-setting-virtual-hosts-for-xampp-in-windows/27754990#27754990

Answer (score 0):

you can access your file by typing its file location like this. if you have a `home.php` inside the `htdocs/test` folder you can type in `localhost/test/home.php`