# Laravel in Xampp

Tags: php, laravel-5

Recently I have installed laravel 5.2 but my home page is not showing at 'localhost' address. It is showing at 'localhost/public' address. I have installed the all files in htdocs folder.Why this 'Public' thing showing up?

Comment: look at this, it guidance you to make vhost and setup laravel up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754367/how-to-setting-virtual-hosts-for-xampp-in-windows/27754990#27754990

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you installed xampp in the default location, a httpd.conf file should be available here:

C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf

Look for 2 adjacent lines:

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
```

And change them to point to laravel's public folder:

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/public"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/public">
```

Comment: This solution works for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I find this tutorial helpful.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ybJYyU5FPv4

Answer (score 0):

Just set up a vhost for your page with the right Document Root like mentioned above. But you dont need to handle Laravel Projects like a default web project. Use `php artisan serve` via console inside your project folder and the page will run at `localhost:8000` default.