# laravel failed to open stream fatal error when running php artisan serve command

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

i had recently installed laravel in windows through composer made a new project named project in my xamp's htdocs folder then run "php artisan serve" comand in cmd but it is giving me error "failed to open stream" here is screenshot [here I ran "php artisan serve" comand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtWsE.png) error is shown in above image I also tried to search my problem on stack overflow but couldn't find any solution that can suit my problem

Comment: Read the docs at laravel.com.  How did you install?  Seems like you're missing the vendor files, normally a `composer install` installs these.  In the future, post formatted text, not images.

Comment: If you are using xamp, why do you need to run this command? Xamp is already serving the directory if it in is htdocs.

Comment: yeah i had installed composer through composer install @Devon

Comment: yes but when I try to access localhost/folder/public/index.php same error occur but this time on the browser window @TaylorFoster

Comment: You need to point Xamp to laravels public folder. [You'll find what you need here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37005895/laravel-in-xampp)

Comment: @KritarthBillorey  Just FYI `composer install` doesn't install composer, it installs the package dependencies for the project.  You must have had an error or version problem in the install if `composer update` worked but `composer install` did not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most files are missing because you have not successfully installed Laravel.

Go to `C:\xampp\htdocs\project>` and type `composer update --no-scripts` or `composer install`

Since you are using xampp, once all the necessary files and packages are downloaded to your project you should be able to access your site through localhost without running `php artisan serve` by visiting

```
http://localhost/project/public
```

NB:Just ensure xampp is running

Answer (score 1):

please go through the documentation first

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4#installation

you did not installed laravel projects correctly. you did not have vendor files. First you have to run :

composer install

dont need php artisan serve in xampp ... just go to

localhost/your_project/public

hope it helps !!!