# Laravel artisan serve error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I get this error when I run the php artisan serve command to launch laravel am a beginner in laravel

> PHP Warning:  require(/home/matynjr/events/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/matynjr/events/artisan on line 18
>
> PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/matynjr/events/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/matynjr/events/artisan on line 18

Comment: Have you run `composer install`?

Comment: @aynber My guess is that this is the problem, maybe add that as an answer?

Comment: @ljubadr That's such a common issue that I think it would probably be a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [laravel failed to open stream fatal error when running php artisan serve command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45825053/laravel-failed-to-open-stream-fatal-error-when-running-php-artisan-serve-command)

Comment: My guess is that the autoloader is not yet generated, try to run `composer install` or perhaps `composer dumpautoload -o` in the root of your laravel installation.

Answer (score 12):

run in your project root folder cmd with `composer update` command

Answer (score 7):

You need to go to your project room and install dependencies. It says that there is no vendor folder. Vendor folder is a part of composer. It holds dependency files inside.

Run `composer install` in the project root. It is a good idea to run `composer update` after that.

Answer (score 5):

If `composer install` / `composer update` isn't working for you, try:

```
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

OR

```
composer update --ignore-platform-reqs
```

After this you should be able to run "`php artisan serve`".

Comment: Why would anyone need to ignore the platform in this case? Do you know what this flag actually means?

Answer (score 2):

For faster results you can use

```
composer update --verbose --prefer-dist
```

Answer (score 1):

on your root folder run `cmd` [by replacing root directory with cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nOkS.png)
or open new terminal, navigate to your project root folder and follow the steps below
1 run `composer install`
2 `composer update`
3 restart your app
4 then run `php artisan serve`

Answer (score 1):

run

```
 composer install
```

in the root directory of your project

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there were some issues in composer.
I resolved it by running this command in cmd in project's root folder:

> composer update

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error emerged because at some point I enter this two commands php "php artisan cache:clear" and "php artisan config:cache".

So, the way a solved my problem was:

1. Type first "php artisan cache:clear"
2. php artisan config:cache
3. npm update
4. composer update

and that's it.