# VirtualHost with default IP address

Tags: wamp, virtualhost

i create new VirtualHost

```
<VirtualHost lar.local>
    DocumentRoot "C:\\wamp\\www\\laravel\\public\\"
    ServerName lar.local
    ServerAlias lar.local
    <Directory "C:\\wamp\\www\\laravel\\public\\"> 
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My host file:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 lar.local
```

When i open - lar.local works fine.

But when i open default WAMP address (127.0.0.1), i get "C:\wamp\www\laravel\public\" also the same directory. Why?

Why with 127.0.0.1 i can't open root server directory (C:\wamp\www\) as before?
How fix this

Comment: why would you do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754367/how-to-setting-virtual-hosts-for-xampp-in-windows/27754990#27754990

Comment: maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ> I need this for my old projects.
I add new virtualhost with 80 port (this is my Apache port), but is the same. 
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\\wamp\\www\\"
    ServerName 127.0.0.1
</VirtualHost>

Comment: [This describes how to create Virtual Hosts properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618) I think the bit you forgot was that you need to also create a Virtual Host for localhost as the default in `httpd.conf` is ignored when Virtual Hosts are defined. You should also add an entery into the hosts file for the IPV6 network as well, like `::1 localhost` and `::1 lar.local` (seperate lines)