# VSCode: php-debug setup

Tags: php, xampp, visual-studio-code

Following the instructions [here](https://github.com/felixfbecker/vscode-php-debug/blob/master/README.md), and I am stuck at the silliest of steps..

> make a simple test.php file, put a phpinfo(); statement in there,
>   then copy the output and paste it into the XDebug installation wizard.

I have created the the test.php file (with  `phpinfo();` as the only statement ), but I can't run it...

What I have done:

I have installed XAMPP, and started Apache on port 8080. `http://localhost:8080/` gets me the XAMPP dashboard, so I know that is ok

I have `"php.validate.executablePath": "C:/xampp/php/php.exe"` in my settings.json

I have a tasks.json build task as follows

```
{
 "version": "0.1.0",
 "command": "php",
 "args": [
  "-S", "127.0.0.1:8080",
  "-t", "${workspaceRoot}"
 ]
}
```

but when I try to run it, I get an error

```
Failed to launch external program php -S 127.0.0.1:8080 -t ${workspaceRoot}.
spawn php ENOENT
```

Is my whole approach (gleaned from various guides on the web) somehow wrong, or what have I missed out? (I am a 20+ years MS dev, but I know zero about php, so sorry if it is a really daft question)

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I managed a workaround, to at least display the test.php file.

Followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754367/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-xampp-windows), but the only way to have multiple sites that I found to work was using separate ports. So I added to `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf` :

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"
    ServerName localhost:8080
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:8081>
    DocumentRoot "C:/mydir/myrootfolder/"
    ServerName localhost:8081
</VirtualHost>
```

and to `C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf`, I added

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and

```
Listen 8080
Listen 8081
```

My `test.php` file was amended to:

```
<?php
  phpinfo();
?>
```

I could then navigate to `http://localhost:8081/test.php` and see the output!

I hope this helps someone else, at least with this stage of the process. I will update if there's anything extra in actually setting up **php-debug** or **x-debug** itself.

Answer (score 1):

Run in console `php -i` or `php -i > phpinfo.txt`.
Copy content output or content `phpinfo.txt` to [Xdebug Wizard](https://xdebug.org/wizard.php)

Download .dll file from this page. And follow instruction.
Add to `php.ini`, for example

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.4.1-5.6-vc11.dll
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_autostart=on
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="C:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.remote_log ="C:\xampp\tmp\xdebug.log"
```

Restart your Apache server. In browser in phpinfo() you see section with Xdebug setting.
Else you are something wrong.
In Visual Studio code in gebug panel push icon with gear and select `php`.

Created `launch.json`.
In gebug panel selected `Listen for Xdebug`. Run debug.

Mark breakpoints in app. Navigate and reload app in browser.

Settings for `mysite.local/test.php`

Create folder "c:/[path-to-xampp]/htdocs/mysite.local"
In this folder create file `test.php`

```
<?php
  phpinfo();
?>
```

Create new virtual host

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName mysite.local
DocumentRoot "c:/[path-to-xampp]/htdocs/mysite.local"
<Directory />
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
   AllowOverride All
   Require all granted
   Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

In file `C:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts` add

```
127.0.0.1 mysite.local
```

Restart your apache server.
Navigate your app in browser: `http://mysite.local`

Comment: I will be adding to this later - because I have been through this process (unsuccessfully) already - but, just to ensure I give the right information ...if I follow your virtual host / hosts instructions, what should be the url to access the site from the browser?