# Set up virtual hosts on Apache (XAMPP, Windows 10)

Tags: apache, xampp, virtualhost, apache2.2

I try to set up virtual host for some local site with XAMPP.

I executed next steps:

1. In "C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf" I added:

```
<VirtualHost *:8081>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:8081>
    DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/fw/public
    ServerName fw.local.com
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/fw/public">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

2. Inside "C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts" I added:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost    
127.0.0.1       fw.local.com
```

3. Restarted Apache.

And...

If I follow to:

```
http://localhost:8081/
```

All is OK: I see my catalog with projects in folder "htdocs".

But! If I follow to:

```
http://fw.local.com/
```

I expect to see result of my "index.php" file inside "..htdocs/fw/public". But I get:

```
This site can’t be reached
fw.local.com refused to connect.
```

File "C:/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf" contains:

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Where I was wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754367/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-xampp-windows/27754990#27754990

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should change: `<VirtualHost *:8081>` to `<VirtualHost *:80>` on both counts, fw.local.com attempts to connect to port 80, not 8081.

**Edit:** You could also keep it the way you have it and connect to: http://fw.local.com:8081/

Comment: Thanks, @Raz0rwire! You are right. But in the global settings also need to change port from 80 to 8081 (I mean XAMPP) for my goal. Tell me please,  if I need to use some exact port for Apache (not 80, for example 8081), can I create virtual host that I can go to "fw.local.com" without 8081?

Comment: You could reverse proxy, but that would be overkill, is there a specific reason for not running on port 80?

Comment: At this moment - no. Just I want to know it if it sometime is required to me. Anyway, many thanks!

Comment: If you want to run on 'just the domain' without specifying a port, you ar required to listen on :80, if you have ssl set up you are required to listen on :443  :) You're welcome, could you maybe accept my answer?

Comment: doesn't worked for me even I added custom port with url but getting `404`