# Windows 10 Magento Local Installation with XAMP problem with Virtual Hosts

Tags: xampp, windows-10, localhost, magento2

I have installed Magento in my personal laptop with XAMP (windows 10) all looks good. Followed the same steps on another laptop and not able to get Magento running.

Found that port 80 is occupied in the new laptop and configured xamp with port 8090, Apache, Phymyadmin and all works good. Following is my configuration for virtual hosts file

```
<VirtualHost *:8090>
    DocumentRoot "C:/M/xampp8.1/htdocs/magento2/pub"
    ServerName kumar.magento245.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:8090>
    DocumentRoot "C:/M/xampp8.1/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost:8090

</VirtualHost>
```

Following in windows hosts file

`127.0.0.1:8090  kumar.magento245.com`

XAMP Apache running on port 8090

when i enter kumar.magento245.com gives 404 error

I assure you the rest of the installation is in sync with my earlier laptop (that dont have any service running on port 80 and i dint changed the hosts file)

Kindly please advise what to be done..
**Not planning to  change/edit the service running on port 80 .**

when i enter kumar.magento245.com gives 404 error..  it should got my local magento running ( installed at C:/M/xampp8.1/htdocs/magento2/pub )

Comment: hosts file does not contain any ports

Comment: thanks i also tried with just 127.0.0.1 kumar.magento245.com in hosts file, still same issue..

Answer (score 1):

I followed a response in the following thread @Raz0rwire and solved my issue.

[Set up virtual hosts on Apache (XAMPP, Windows 10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43953097/set-up-virtual-hosts-on-apache-xampp-windows-10?rq=1)

accessed the url like this kumar.magento245.com:8090  port number at the end..

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO @kumar2023,

There could be multiple possibilities for resolving this issue,
in this case, I would prefer the below steps :

1. Try running Magento with the direct browser URL ie. https://yourmagnetopath/pub and ensure at least my Magento has been installed
   correctly
2. Try removing the default ports and their entries, in my case well I am using ubuntu hence there could be a case of caching if you tried multiple times with the same URL.
3. Try with the incognito browser or I would prefer a new browser where you haven't tried to run this URL.
4. Just give a try with the newer domain (again there could be a reason for caching)

Comment: Thanks Sagar, appreciate your reply. i tried with different browsers and also incognito nothing working. for Step 1, hope i understood well, http://C:/M/xampp8.1/htdocs/magento2/pub.com  it is just opening file directory.. tried the same with working installation from other laptop..its the same.