# Laravel version: 5.4.28 api routes not working on localhost

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I downloaded Laravel 5.4.28 and created one api route. Nothing works on localhost. I am using XAMPP on Windows 8.1 as local development.

But everything is working fine on server. I also notice one strange thing. It will work on localhost if I create virtual host on localhost. like below.

```
php artisan serve
```

Is that true? or Am I missing anything?

My api routes are like this...

> http://localhost:1234/adminapi/public/api/v1/authenticateuser

Comment: hello @pankaj welcome to android development first  that prompt is not from APP  (this is System that install your app) You can click install and the package gets updated (hope you got my point)

Comment: The list of really working routers you can use to see using the command `php artisan route:list`. Have you tried so to do? Is your address on the list?

Comment: Are you sure that is the right URL? First of all I think routes in API.php have a api prefix so it should be /api/adminapi/public/api/v1/authenticateuser however, it may also be possible you're trying to access an endpoint via the project and public folder when you should just go from the public. Maybe try /api/v1/authenticate or /api/api/v1/authenticate user?

Answer (score 1):

If your XAMPP works normally with normal `PHP` pages, did you check which version of php XAMPP uses ? the minimum required version is

```
PHP >= 5.6.4
```

[Laravel Official Website](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4#server-requirements)

The default version of XAMPP's `PHP` framework is `5.6.30`

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same problem, it turned out that I had only problem with PHP version I just upgraded the version of php.ini from `5.6.3` to `7.0.1` new versions of XAMPP have them both !

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to create virtual host for your project like `yourprojectname.local`. and test your app through this url.
If you not create virtualhost then you need to give whole path for access laravel api like `localhost/yourprojectdirectory/public/adminapi/public/api/v1/authenticateuser`
You can bellow link refer to the creating virtual host

http://foundationphp.com/tutorials/apache_vhosts.php
OR 
[How To Set Up Apache Virtual Hosts on XAMPP (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754367/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-xampp-windows)

Answer (score 0):

When you do `php artisan serve` and load the URL returned by that command do you see laravels welcome page? If not then you haven't installed it correctly. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4

Answer (score 0):

If you install fresh laravel app, you base api prefix must be equal `api`.

you route in api.php

```
Route::get('test', 'TestController@test');
```

If now you run `php artisan serve` command, api will be available to 
`localhost:8000/api/test`.

Hope, I help you.

Answer (score 0):

The `php artisan serve` command doesn't create a virtual host, it is just a shortcut for the [PHP Builtin Webserver](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php), something PHP has out of the box, so the point of using it is to start testing your application as fast as you could, you just need to install `PHP`, `Composer` and your application is up (if you don't need anything else, of course). But if you already have `Nginx` installed, there is no point at all, just use it.

It's **not wise** to use the Builtin Webserver in production.

Answer (score 0):

There's a property in `config/app.php` called `url`.

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application URL
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This URL is used by the console to properly generate URLs when using
| the Artisan command line tool. You should set this to the root of
| your application so that it is used when running Artisan tasks.
|
*/

'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),
```

By default it links to `.env` file's property called `APP_URL`. XAMP usually requires you to navigate to `localhost/project_folder` before you can even access your project, hence why you need to set your `url` property to the one you're using.

Second, API routes usually are prefixed with `/api/` and do require a `X-REQUESTED-WITH: XMLHttpRequest` header.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same with Apache on Windows. Following the next steps below, it worked for me.

First, look for your file `httpd.conf` into Apache.

Find the section...

```
<Directory /var/www/>
```

Change

```
AllowOverride None
```

to

```
AllowOverride All
```

Finally, restart the Apache service.