# Laravel routing failing after moved to other server

Tags: php, laravel, routes

In my Dev server which is on my pc, I set up vhost to change my URL to `dmb.dev` to remove the public in URL so many of my routes started at `/` slash. After I transfer my project to our test server I configure some settings to allow me to remove public. Now, all assets are working except my routes because I'm still having `http://server/dmb` instead of `http://server` I'm getting an error of `Failed to load resource: /myurl`.

My sample routes

```
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index')->name('index');
Route::get('/generate_bing', 'PagesController@generateImage')->name('index.getImage');
Route::get('/users', 'PagesController@showUser')->name('users')->middleware('auth','role:owner');
```

My root htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Do I need to change all routes to dmb/etc.. I'm thinking of solution of removing my root folder so it would look like `http://server`, but there's other project on our htdocs so I need to remain it store in their folders. BTW I'm using xampp

Comment: check .htaccess and .env file

Comment: apache, nginx? windows server / linux server ?

Comment: `dmb` is your folder under public_html on server?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay Yes it is

Comment: Take a look at [Full guideline to make VHOST (Virtual Host) on XAMPP/WAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754367/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-xampp-windows/27754990#27754990)

Comment: Also, this one could help [How to install Laravel 5 with Xampp (Windows)](https://www.codementor.io/magarrent/how-to-install-laravel-5-xampp-windows-du107u9ji)

Answer (score 0):

As you have `dmb` as your folder under public_html, adding one line to your htaccess would solve the issue.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /dmb/                      // ADD THIS LINE HERE

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```