# Which stack to use for developing Laravel app on Windows?

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

Although Laravel documentation does not mention using XAMPP, I would like to know whether using XAMPP stack, sticks to the best practices for Laravel development on Windows?

Which of one of the stacks (LAMP, WAMP, XAMPP, Laragon, Homestead) do you recommend for developing with Laravel on windows?

Comment: yes you can use xampp and use laravel framework with it

Comment: @Ghost is it the best practice?

Comment: Yes you can use. I'm using bitnami WAMP stack to develop laravel websites. And it works fine.
https://bitnami.com/stack/wamp/installer

Comment: @Bart just use whatever you're comfortable with, if you have a mac, then you can't force yourself with linux or windows, that's whats good about web development, you can use whatever platform you're in

Comment: @Ghost what about CI? Is it equally easy to set up CI on all platforms?

Comment: @KavindaPrabhath I know that I can use this, but I am trying to find the best approach....

Comment: Best practice would be to dev in an environment that is close as possible to what it would be running in with production.  Learn enough linux to set up a VirtualBox machine, get a friend to help, post on unix.stackexchange, etc.

Comment: Xampp or wamp both are fine it is no thing more than Apache and MySql served for you

Comment: I would also suggest vhost setting check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754367/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-xampp-windows

Comment: As @ivanivan suggested are there any disadvantages in using Homestead in comparison to XAMPP?

Comment: I have edited my answer to your post requirement about homestead. kindly check it. @Bart

Answer (score 1):

Why not use laragon.. https://laragon.org/ free and has laravel built in

Answer (score 0):

[Source](https://studyreadeducate.blogspot.in/2017/03/introduction-of-xampp-lamp-wamp.html)

Xampp

XAMPP stands for Cross Platform ,Apache , MariaDB (MySQL) ,PHP ,Perl.
XAMPP is a free and open source cross-platform web server solution stack package developed by Apache Friends, consisting mainly of the Apache HTTP Server, MariaDB database, and interpreters for scripts written in the PHP and Perl programming languages.

Advantages of XAMPP :-

It is Easy to Install as compare to other web server's like WAMP.
It is Multi Cross Platform which means XAMPP is available for Windows          and Linux. It also comes with a number of other modules including OpenSSL, phpMyAdmin, MediaWiki, Joomla, WordPress and more. XAMPP is offered in both a full and a standard version (Smaller version). You can start and stop the whole webserver+database stack with one command.

Disadvantages of XAMPP :-

Configuration and Setting is tough to do as compare to WAMP Server.

Wamp

WAMP is sometimes used as an abbreviated name for the software stack Windows, Apache, MySQL, PHP. It is derived from LAMP which stands for Linux, Apache, MySQL, and PHP. As the name implies, while LAMP is used on Linux servers, WAMP is used on Windows servers.

Advantages of WAMP :-

It is easy to Use. (Changing Configuration). WAMP makes easy to code PHP and Creating Data bases (in MySQL) in Windows platform. WAMP is Available for both 64 bit and 32 bit system.

Disadvantages of WAMP :-

It is not easy to install as compare to XAMPP.

There is also a lite version of xampp available for limited usage. Usually you can set it up with either one but I prefer xampp over wamp.

Lately op tries to include laravel homestead in the list so a very detailed description of homestead is [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/homestead) in its documentation. And for pros and cons of using homestead is given [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/6-reasons-move-laravel-homestead/).

If you just only want to learn laravel than homestead is fine because its specially developed for laravel framework but if you want to give it a try to gain server knowledge and setting up of the same with different settings I suggest you using xampp in which you will come to know some very basic server settings used for hosting.

Comment: are you able to show some page render speed comparisons between solutions, cause I believe it might be crucial case here? I would gladly accept your solution then...