# How to install existing prestashop on localhost with APache2? Having pb configuring .conf and virtual hosts

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, localhost, apache2, prestashop

After installing XAMPP, I downloaded the project code and the SQL database:
1) I downloaded the database on phpmyadmin
2)copied the project in var/www/html

Now I am trying to configure Apache2, going through etc/apache2 by adding a file in sites-available containing:

<
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

```
    <Directory /var/www/html/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <IfModule mod_dir.c>
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.html index.xhtml index.htm
    </IfModule>
```

then disabled the default and enabling mine.

But when I go on localhost:8000, there is no connection and the database seems to be on port 3306.

Could you help me understand better what should I do or what I am doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: phpmyadmin is not a DBMS, this is a php tool used to manage MySQL databases.

Comment: I have a SQL database, so I need to manage it..so if I am wrong what should I do?

Comment: Ah you are trying to go to phpmyadmin?

Comment: you mention xampp and apache2/etc folder, is this xampp for windows?
this might help you to configure your xampp correctly, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754367/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-xampp-windows
And for the database if you can access phpmyadmin, change the shop url value to localhost if it's not.

Comment: sorry I didn'nt mention I am on Ubuntu. And I already change the domain url name to localhost. I am still having the XAMPP welcome page.

Comment: @ClaireDemont nagivate to `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` or `http://localhost:8000/phpmyadmin`

Comment: i still believe it's the server configuration that is your problem. do you have that port 8000 open? do you have anything in ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log?
what are the rights/ownership of the files in /var/www/html (are they accessible?)