# does not open a local site

Tags: php, xampp

I have already checked everything 10 times and remade, but I did not understand why he does not open the site itself.

[image]

What actions did I take

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc - 127.0.0.1 aoidb.com

C:\xampp\htdocs\aoidb - create folder (aoidb)

```html
<VirtualHost aoidb.com:8080>
 DocumentRoot C:\xampp\htdocs\aoidb
 ServerName aoidb.com
 ServerAdmin admin@aoidb.com
 <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\aoidb">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  Allow from all
  Require all granted
  IndexIgnore /
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . index.php
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Not sure. Restarted your Apache? Changed the port? (80 vs 8080) Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754367/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-xampp-windows help?

Comment: It was necessary to conjure with ports and why that on 8080 does not work, and if to leave VirtualHost aoidb.com:80, it will swear that port 80 busy xampp. It was necessary to change ports and to alter and it seems to work.

Comment: Well your screenshot says you're on port 80 and from the looks of it that is your "localhost"/default configuration from Apache, not the VirtualHost you posted. Have you taken a look at the answer from the link I posted?