# Making virtual host in xampp for laravel

Tags: laravel, xampp

Virtual host is most beneficial to run project with good url like:
http://example.test/ how to make it in xampp ?

Comment: there are other already answered questions on this topic. use some google search before asking a question. [How To Set Up Apache Virtual Hosts on XAMPP (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754367/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-xampp-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Open hosts file. On Windows, it's usually located at C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts, while on macOS and Linux, it's found at /etc/hosts.
Add a New Entry: 127.0.0.1   yourlaravelapp.test

Add a Virtual Host Configuration:
Windows, it's usually located at C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf. On macOS, it's typically located at /Applications/XAMPP/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/your-laravel-project/public"
ServerName yourlaravelapp.test
ServerAlias www.yourlaravelapp.test
</VirtualHost>
```

And after that restart apache

Answer (score 0):

First, open your `hosts` file,

- Window -> `C:\Windows\System64\drivers\etc\hosts`
- Linux/macOS ->
  `\etc\hosts`

Add below line in `hosts` file,

```
127.0.0.1    yourvirtualhost.name
```

Configure your Apache in `httpd-vhosts.conf`,

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/yourproject"
    ServerName yourvirtualhost.name
</VirtualHost>
```

And then restart your xampp, now you can access using `yourvirtualhost.name`.