# apache set virtual host access 403 access forbidden,why?

Tags: php, apache, virtualhost

The environment is OS X 10.10.2 Yosemite and I'm running a XAMPP server.
my configurations:

**httpd.conf**

```
<Directory />
    #Options FollowSymLinks
    #Require all granted
    AllowOverride All
    #XAMPP
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
<Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
# Virtual hosts
Include /Applications/XAMPP/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

**httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin luckyyulin@sina.cn
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/makefriend99/1"
    ServerName makefriend99.com
    ServerAlias www.makefriend99.com
    ErrorLog "logs/makefriend99/error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/makefriend99/access_log" common
    <Directory /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/makefriend99/1>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin luckyyulin@sina.cn
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/angular"
    ServerName ngaction.com
    ServerAlias www.ngaction.com
    ErrorLog "logs/angular/error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/angular/access_log" common
    <Directory /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/angular>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**hosts**

```
127.0.0.1 makefriend99.com
127.0.0.1 ngaction.com
```

I access makefriend99.com is successful before adding ngation.com, besides localhost/makefriend99/1.But It’s failed to access ngation.com,localhost/makefriend99/1 and localhost/angular of 403 access 
 forbidden after adding ngaction.com, makefriend99.com is successful,access localhost to makefriend99.com.
I have tried some ways saw in the Internet,but I haven’t solved the problem,who can help me to explain why and give some answers to solve it?

Comment: I also want to find what's the answer for this, kindly mention me if you found one.

Comment: I had this issue with local host&apache. I ended up changing the permissions of the WebServer in the root to gain access. http://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-permissions-should-my-website-files-folders-have-on-a-linux-webserver

Comment: @5ervant I‘m happy to that

Comment: @WillCampbell how to change the permission of the webserver in the root? I have chmoded the directory of access,but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this question may answer it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24665604/3990714 and this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9117898/3990714

**If the first didn't work, try this:**

[**Note:** I don't use XAMPP so this step is probably irrelevant and you may want to customly CHMOD all the subdirectories in your XAMPP file]: 
Somewhere along the lines, Apple moved the Apache WebServer folder and a bunch of permission errors arose resulting in the 403 Access Forbidden Error (me included).

I had this issue specifically with my localhost, but I assume it will be the same concept here.

In your terminal: 
Go to the Home directory via:

```
$ cd
```

Then we will go up the directory tree.

```
$ cd ../../
```

To get to the Macintosh HD disk (root directory). 
Then:

```
$ cd Library
```

If you type the `ls` command you should see everything. Then chmod from the prior link (seen [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-permissions-should-my-website-files-folders-have-on-a-linux-webserver)) to the WebServer folder. You may have to chmod all subdirectories in that folder too, but I didn't encounter that issue when I experienced this error.

Comment: Thanks a lot,the answer of first question solve my issue,navigate ngaction.com can access my site,but I don't know why navigate localhost access one of virtual hosts(makefriend99.com),can you help me?

Comment: @5ervant the first question solve my issue,you can try.

Answer (score 2):

How about trying to permit an access by adding the `Require all granted` directive to a specific `VirtualHost` `Directory`?

```
        ...
        #Order deny,allow    <- You can try to remove this
        #Allow from all      <- and that if they're just a crap.
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see, both of them are running at the same IP. If they also run on the same port, you have to change the port of one of them.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Directory />
#Options FollowSymLinks
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>
```