# Website outside the htdocs

Tags: php, xampp

I am configuring website outside the htdocs and I did all changes what are describe here [Virtual Host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408/#2471).
But partially it done but routes are not working. Only Home page showing. rest of page showing `Object not found!.`

like

```
<VirtualHost *:81>
DocumentRoot "C:\DevlopmentApps\VirtualMarket"
ServerName sjb.localhost
<Directory C:\DevlopmentApps\VirtualMarket>
   Options Indexes 
   AllowOverride none
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Now

```
http://sjb.localhost:81/sjb is working
http://sjb.localhost:81/sjb/find/ not working
```

Comment: please add virtual host configuration

Comment: above I mention the link. Exactly i did. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408/make-xampp-apache-serve-file-outside-of-htdocs#2471

Comment: it seems you have an issue with allowOverride in `<Directory>` try replacing `<Directory>....</Directory>` with `<Directory C:\DevlopmentApps\VirtualMarket>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>`

Comment: so what should i do? i am newbe in php so i dont understand that.

Comment: now it giving **Access forbidden!**

Comment: then try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110179/adding-virtualhost-fails-access-forbidden-error-403-xampp-windows-7?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i figure out some thing that other should be aware with.

If want to configure outside the htdocs the need to do following steps in the follwong link

[Virtual host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408/make-xampp-apache-serve-file-outside-of-htdocs#2471)

Here is some thing Deprecated. `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110179/adding-virtualhost-fails-access-forbidden-error-403-xampp-windows-7?answertab=votes#tab-top`

```
<Directory ..........>
    # AllowOverride All      # Deprecated
    # Order Allow,Deny       # Deprecated
    # Allow from all         # Deprecated

    # --New way of doing it
    Require all granted    
</Directory>
```

Now one thing which fixed my issue is

```
Options All
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
```